# Using reg ex in PHP to query MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying to query a MYSQL database using regular expressions. I am looking to get the values under columns with this pattern 1234X32X12.

I have written some pseudo-code, but I am unfamiliar with regular expressions, so I was hoping someone could help me out.

**CODE:**

```
if ($transposed_array[$i][0] starts with number)
    {
        $sid = regex something /^[0-9]*/
        $gid = regex something /X[0-9]*X/
        $gid = remove first and last character from $gid
        $qid = regex something /[0-9]*$/

        $question_text = mysql_query("select question from table where sid = ".$sid." and gid = ".$gid." and qid = ".$qid." limit 1");
        $transposed_array[$i][0] = $question_test
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports regex matching directly in its SQL commands, check out [its manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

```
select col from table where col regexp '^h';
```

([see this at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e992/1/0))

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to read into the appropriate section of the [Mysql-Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html), which is very detailed on how to perform a regular expression search.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to `mysql`'s regular expression match function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

IF its an X you are splitting on then this would do:

```
$var = "1234X32X12";

$bits = explode("X", $var);

var_dump( $bits);

array
  0 => string '1234' (length=4)
  1 => string '32' (length=2)
  2 => string '12' (length=2)
```

But I get the feeling X could be any alphabetical character, is it?

Comment: No X is the split. so the number 1234X32X12 is equivalent to survey_idXpage_idXquestion_id...thanks for your help